# Проблема с переключением языка на странице

Tags: php

на второй странице сайта есть возможность смены языка , но язык меняется только со второй попытке, когда на главной странице смена языка реагирует с первой попытки. В чём может быть проблема?
**вот мой код**

```
    <?php
session_start();

        $dict = parse_ini_file($_SESSION['lang'].'.ini');

if($_GET['lang']) {
    $_SESSION['lang'] = trim(strip_tags($_GET['lang']));

}
else if ($_COOKIE['lang']) {
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $_COOKIE['lang'];
}
else {
    $_SESSION['lang'] = 'en';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего, у Вас не предусмотрена перезагрузка/обновление страницы после смены языка на второй странице. Поэтому, переменные меняются, но сработаеют они только после перезагрузки.
Поставьте принудительный header с перезагрузкой, в случае смены lang. Возможно, потребуется дополнить условие сравнения выбранного и существующего lang.